# SQL Server 2008 R2 custom database as system database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

On our development server, we have a custom database that is now showing up in the System Databases folder in the SSMS Object Explorer tree.

I was wondering if anyone knows:

1. Why it would show up there?
2. How we would move it back to the correct place?

We have already tried the usual: rebooted, and tried dragging it out of the system folder

Comment: Can you show a screen shot? What version of Management Studio are you using? What is @@VERSION of the server? What is the name of the custom database?

Comment: Perhaps the database has been configured as the distribution database for replication?  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1381740-1292-1.aspx

Comment: Thank you @cgsmks!!  That link was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cgsmks, the answer was to disable replication.  The database had been marked as the distributor database during replication configuration, which moves it to the system folder!

From the link http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1381740-1292-1.aspx posted by cgsmks:

> To undo the operation, I right clicked on the Replication Folder and selected Disable Publishing and Distribution. I then selected the Yes, Disable Publishing on this Server option and completed the wizard.